# Is WebSocket/Web RTC suitable for download of many little files instead of tons of GETs?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, webrtc

I'm making a JavaScript Web app that must pull hundreds of fragments of JSON off the server and am concerned about the hit from so many HTTP GETs. There's no opportunity to concatenate the fragments (so as to have one GET) because the server/client doesn't know in advance what fragments it's going to need to GET until runtime.

Question is: would it be insanity to use something like WebSocket or Web RTC as the transport, with the client firing requests down the socket and the server grabbing each file as requested and firing it back down the socket?

Assuming that the server is fast enough at loading the files, this would be way more responsive that HTTP, right?

I guess I lose out on caching, but I can live with that.

Comment: WebSockets are fine for that task, but why can't the server concatenate those fragments on runtime?

Comment: It's a graphics application where the client composes a scene graph from library assets (the JSON fragments) provided by the server, and the graph compositions required by clients cannot be known in advance by the server.

Comment: OK, I see. Yes, WebSockets or even WebRTC would be faster than multiple GET requests, since they have much less overhead.